# 画面回転時にUIViewのサイズ変更に伴いaddSublayerしたAVPlayerLayerもサイズ変更するには

Tags: swift

swiftで画面回転時にあるUIView(view1)のサイズがconstraintにより変更します。
しかし、そのUIViewにaddSublayerで追加したAVPlayerLayerのサイズが自動的に変更しません。

```
// 下記、ソースの一部
// Viewを生成.
let videoPlayerView = AVPlayerView(frame: view1.bounds)
// UIViewのレイヤーをAVPlayerLayerにする.
let layer = videoPlayerView.layer as! AVPlayerLayer
layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
layer.player = videoPlayer
// レイヤーを追加する.
view1.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

上記ソースのlayerをUIview(view1)が変わったら変更させたいと思っています。画面回転時は、

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {}
```

で処理できると思いますが、addSubLayerで追加したAVPlayerLayerのサイズはどうやって変更させたらいいのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

上記ソースだと、`AVPlayerView`の`layer`プロパティは`videoPlayerView`に紐付いているのではないでしょうか？

なので、わざわざレイヤーだけを取り出して`addSubLayer`せずに、素直に`view1`に`addSubView`して、上下左右の`NSLayoutConstraint`を作成、適用するか、`InterfaceBuilder`で`view1`に`AVPlayerView`を`view1`と同じサイズにAutoLayoutを設定して`@IBOutlet`にすればいい気がします(`view1`がそもそも`AVPlayerView`でも問題無いならそのほうがいい気もします)